# jQuery slide-tab-out issue

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-animate, slide

I have a problem with my slide tab out.I want "book div" to be at the same position as "menu"(under menu) but when you hover--> to slide out (animate) to the right about 5 px ( literally just the movement) and when mouse leaves come back to the same position. Its gonna be working sort of like a button to navigate to another page. 
At the moment is sliding over "black div". Does anyone know how to make it work? Any suggestions will be appreciated.. Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.menu').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#menunav').stop().animate({
    'left': '0px'
    },300);
    });
    $('#menunav').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menunav').animate({
    'left':'-100px'},2000);
    });

$('.book').hover(function(){
    $('.book').animate({
    'margin-right': '0px'
    },300);
    });
    $('.book').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.book').animate({
    'margin-right':'10px'},300);
    });
});

   </script>
```

my html :

```
<body>
  <section id="menunav">
  <aside class="div_1">div_1</aside>
  <aside class="menu">menu</aside>
  <aside class="book">booking</aside>
  </section>
 </body>
```

css:

```
#menunav{
         position:absolute;
         width:150px;
         left:-100px;
         top:200px;
         background-color:transparent;
         height:150px;
         padding-right:10px;
         }
  .div_1{
         background-color:black;
         top:0px;
         float:left;
         height:150px;
         width:100px;
         color: white;
         }
   .menu{
         background-color:yellow;
         float:right;
         top:0px;
         height:70px;
         width:48px;
         }
   .book{
         top:70px;
         background-color:red;
         float:right;
         height:80px;
         width:48px;
         margin-right:10px;
         margin-left:-10px;
         }
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How about this?**

change your js to this:

```
$('.menu').mouseover(function () { 
    $(this).parent().stop().animate({left: '0px'}, 'fast');
}).mouseout().parent().mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({left: '-100px'}, 'slow');
});
$('.book').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({right: '-5px'}, 'fast');
}, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({right: '0px'}, 'fast');
});
```

and your css to this:

```
#menunav, .div_1, .menu, .book {position:absolute}
#menunav, .div_1 {height:150px}
#menunav {
    left:-100px;
    top:200px;
    width:150px;
}
.div_1 {
    background-color:black;
    width:100px;
    color: white;
    z-index:2;
}
.menu,.book{width:45px;right:0;padding:5px}
.menu {
    background-color:yellow;
    top:0px;
    height:60px;
}
.book {
    top:70px;
    background-color:red;
    height:70px;
}
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/5PSJr/

Comment: umm still not quite right because "booking" has to work individually. If you hover only booking - it should slide to the right only "booking" not the "menu".

Comment: did you use this script located in head section: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> ??

Comment: so if they were in two separate containers then would be easier to make hover effect?

Comment: hmm not sure what I did wrong but I copied your code from fiddle and its not working .. it doesnt slide at all.. :(

Comment: I got it working how you've described. check out the update on the fiddle and see if it works. If you're having problems getting it to work on your page, send me a link if you can and I can see whats going on.

Comment: FiLeVeR10 - thank you so much! it does work - excellent job again!

Comment: Do you know how to make a fixed position of this navMenu relative to the another div (parent)not a browser window??

Comment: I actually want to place navMenu in the div="parent" - which is height=1700px and is located under first div <header> which is height = 500px; : so that means when u are at main page u dont see the navMennu, it appears only when u scroll the page about 700px down and then position is fixed to related div = parent. Is that make sense?

Comment: thank you very much! works just as I wanted! once again thank you for your time :))

Comment: hi FiLeVeR10 :) umm do you maybe know how to animate menunav so will slowly slide right not show, I have changed #parent - left: -150px and i cancel display: none, and in js $('#parent').stop().animate({left:0},'slow'); it does slide but when i scroll up and down window - menu disappear completely.Thank you so much for your help again..